# Howto debug: Rails after_commit seems to not get fired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, observers

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adverts
end

class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

I also have an observer on `Advert` that looks like this:

```
class AdvertObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def before_save advert
    @should_update_car_price = advert.price_changed?
    return true #An ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved will be thrown if return false
  end

  def after_commit advert
    enqueue_car_price_refresh_job_if_necessary(advert)

    reset_async_processing_indicators!
  end

  def reset_async_processing_indicators!
    @should_update_car_price = nil
  end

  #
  # Async processing
  #

  def enqueue_car_price_refresh_job_if_necessary advert
    WorkerJobs::CarPriceRefreshJob.perform_async(advert.car_id) if @should_update_car_price
  end

end
```

Now, the basic idea is, that I need to make sure that the async_processing of the `CarPriceRefreshJob` is first enqueued for processing AFTER the advert has been persisted. The problem is though, that it depends if the `advert.price` has changed or not (dirty) which is not available in an `after_commit`. This is why I instead set a "flag" in `before_save`: `@should_update_car_price`. This seems to work, however there seems to be a few cases in my database where the price on car was NOT synced with the advert (the async job was not run, maybe not enqueued). If I manually enqueue the `CarPriceRefreshJob` for one of these not updated records, it updates as it should, and hence I'm suspecting the callback rather than the job itself.

As stated I'm suspecting the implementation I made of the callback, but I'm very unsure how I can possible debug it? I made tests for all cases I can think of, and they all pass.

I'm running rails 4 BTW with postgresql 9.3

Comment: I assume you have the gem `rails-observers` included?

Comment: Yes!, and for the record, I do not use `update_column` or `update_columns` anywhere...

Comment: I'm not sure it'll be the callback, it might be that the `AdvertObserver` object isn't the same, but recreated so your variable isn't set correctly.  Can you try using `advert.previous_changes` [instead](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes)

Comment: I thought about that as well, but is this something you know could happen, or is it just a guess?

Comment: It could definitely happen, but it's just a guess. I don't have anything to back up that is what is happening.

Comment: Okay, I tried with the `advert.previous_changes` and it doesn't make any difference. I'm asking myself now - could it be that the after_commit is newer fired in some cases?

Comment: The after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are guaranteed to be called for all models created, updated, or destroyed within a transaction block. If any exceptions are raised within one of these callbacks, they will be ignored so that they don't interfere with the other callbacks. As such, if your callback code could raise an exception, you'll need to rescue it and handle it appropriately within the callback. - From the guides, so looks like you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use instance variables on Observers. They are singletons and therefore the instance variables persist when observing other objects.

> Loading Observers register themselves in the model class they observe,
>   since it is the class that notifies them of events when they occur. As
>   a side-effect, when an observer is loaded its corresponding model
>   class is loaded.
>
> Up to (and including) Rails 2.0.2 observers were instantiated between
>   plugins and application initializers. Now observers are loaded after
>   application initializers, so observed models can make use of
>   extensions.
>
> If by any chance you are using observed models in the initialization
>   you can still load their observers by calling ModelObserver.instance
>   before. **Observers are singletons and that call instantiates and
>   registers them.**

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails-observers/0.1.2/ActiveRecord/Observer

This should be catched with a test that saves 2 objects one after another in the same spec.